# Separating a string to make a variable in linux

Tags: linux

I am new to linux and using the command line and am having some difficulty taking part of a directory name and setting it as a variable. I am trying to take "Led Zeppelin - Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3" and make a variable that is defined as "Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3".

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us. Stack Overflow prefers that you show some effort.

Comment: I was able to get my script to work, thank you very much everyone for the help. I apologize if this was a trivial question, still tring to figure out everything

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's instruments do you need to solve your question, but you can do it with sed:

```
~$ echo "Led Zeppelin - Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3" | sed -e "s/^.*\- //"
Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3
```

If you need to set the result in varaible, so what's variable? bash? Something else? Try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="Led Zeppelin - Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3"

updated_line=$(echo "$line" | sed -e "s/^.*\- //")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ str="Led Zeppelin - Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3"
$ var=`echo $str | sed -r 's/.*- (.*)/\1/'`
$ echo $var
Over the Hills and Far Away.mp3
```